# GenericBeanDefinition with MethodInvokingFactoryBean

Tags: spring, javabeans

I want to dynamically create the bean and set some property values returned by the method invocations of other bean.

Without dynamic bean creation, I have the following in my spring config file:

```
<bean id="mybean" class="com.class.mybean">
    <property name="customerName">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetObject" ref="otherBean" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="getCustomerName()" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

With dynamic bean creation, here is my code

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.factory = beanFactory;

        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = ((BeanDefinitionRegistry )factory);  
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();  
        beanDefinition.setBeanClass(MyBeanClass.class);  
        beanDefinition.setLazyInit(false);  
        beanDefinition.setAbstract(false);  
        beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);  
        //beanDefinition.setScope("session");  
        MutablePropertyValues values = new MutablePropertyValues();
        values.addPropertyValue("customerName", ????);
        beanDefinition.setPropertyValues(values);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition("myDynamicBean",beanDefinition);  

}
```

What is the equivalent way in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of xml bean definition you should use class bean definition. For this purpose you should use    `@Configuration` annotation on a class that defines your application context. Here is an example [Spring Configuration](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-java-configuration.html)